# Hive 0.13 connection through SpagoBI 5.0

Tags: hadoop, hive, spagobi

I have made connection from SpagoBI 5.0 to Hive 0.13, when I query

```
select * from table
```

I get success. But when I try some joins or aggregations I get this error:

```
An unexpected error occured while executing dataset:  
Error while processing statement: FAILED: 
Execution Error, return code 1 from  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

I am using ubuntu 14.04
locally installed SpagoBI 5.0 server
Hive connection : remote through JDBC hive driver and Putty SSH Tunneling

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution to my own question after hell lot of google research:

first i thought the error was due to missing jar files but it was simple permission issue.

after following this great post in web :

http://www.hadoopinrealworld.com/fixing-org-apache-hadoop-security-accesscontrolexception-permission-denied/

after digging in hadoop error log files, main error was:

org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=anonymous, access=EXECUTE, inode="staging":ubuntu:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x

so i simply given writes to the staging directory in which the intermediate mapping was done:

hadoop fs -chown anonymous:anonymous /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging

and that solved my problem

now i can run my HIVE aggregation and Joins commands through SpagoBI interface which is connected to HIVE database through JDBC connection.